# Manifest for higher-kinded type missing

Tags: scala, manifest, higher-kinded-types

I am having trouble with scalac not finding a manifest for a higher-kinded internal type I want to use. Consider some list like type with a constructor:

```
trait L[S, A]

def emptyList[S, A: Manifest]: L[S, A] = ???
```

Now another type which gets constructed from its companion object like this:

```
object Tree {
  private class Leaf[S, A]
  private class Impl[S, A](l: L[S, Leaf[S, A]]) extends Tree[S, A]

  def empty[S, A]: Tree[S, A] = new Impl(emptyList[S, Leaf[S, A]])
}
trait Tree[S, A]
```

It fails because scalac wants a manifest for type `Leaf[S, A]`. Why isn't that available? I don't want to relax visibility of `Leaf` and clutter the constructor by asking to pass in a manifest argument.

I don't understand this at all—I thought that from the JVM perspective, the arrays that are constructed in `L` boil down to `Array[Leaf[_, _]]` aka `Array[java.lang.Object]`, so what's the point of this refusal?

Any ways to find the manifest?

Comment: Is this effectively a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8190521/97777 ?

Comment: @Duncan: I don't think so. I have read that one before I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide manifest for all your parameters, in effect creating a complete manifest chain:

```
def emptyList[ S, A : Manifest ] {}
class Leaf[ S, A ]
def emptyTree[ S: Manifest, A : Manifest ] { emptyList[ S, Leaf[ S, A ]]}
```